# trying to develop typing game using libgdx in android

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to create multiple independent `Texture` objects with key words on it falling from top to bottom and a key board displaying at bottom to type the letter on the texture object to capture it and generate new objects repeatedly for given time interval I have gone through the wiki's code for help but when I'm trying to display the words on the texture objects they change the letter on every `Texture` object on the `Batch`

```
package com.example.jtech.bubbletypinggame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class BubbleTypingGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private Texture [] dropImage = new Texture[5];
    private Texture bucketImage;
    private Texture background;
    private Sound dropSound;
    private Music rainMusic;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Rectangle bucket;
    private Array<CustomRectangle> raindrops;
    private Array<String> rainKeyWords;
    private Sprite mySprite;
    CustomRectangle raindrop;

    private long lastDropTime;

    String[] chars = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    int i = 0;
    String captionString;
    private BitmapFont font;
    int j = 0;
    int x = 10, y = 740;


    @Override
    public void create() {

        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.RED);


        //load backgroud image for the game
        background = new Texture("background_nebula.jpg");

        // load the images for the droplet and the bucket, 64x64 pixels each
        dropImage [0] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("balloon_a.png"));
        dropImage [1] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("balloon_b.png"));
        dropImage [2] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("balloon_c.png"));
        dropImage [3] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("balloon_d.png"));
        dropImage [4] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("balloon_e.png"));

        // 25JANwORKING//


        //25JANWORKING//

        bucketImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bucket.png"));

        // load the drop sound effect and the rain background "music"
        dropSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("drop.mp3"));
        rainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));

        // start the playback of the background music immediately
        rainMusic.setLooping(true);
        rainMusic.play();

        // create the camera and the SpriteBatch
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        // create a Rectangle to logically represent the bucket
        bucket = new Rectangle();
        bucket.x = 800 / 2 - 64 / 2; // center the bucket horizontally
        bucket.y = 20; // bottom left corner of the bucket is 20 pixels above the bottom screen edge
        bucket.width = 64;
        bucket.height = 64;


        // create the raindrops array and spawn the first raindrop
        raindrops = new Array<CustomRectangle>();
        rainKeyWords = new Array<String>();
        spawnRaindrop();

    }


    private void spawnRaindrop() {
        raindrop = new CustomRectangle();
        raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800-100);
        raindrop.y = 480;
        raindrop.width = 100;
        raindrop.height = 50;
        raindrop.keyWord = "k";

        raindrops.add(raindrop);
        lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        if(i==chars.length){
            i=0;
        }
        captionString = chars[i];
        rainKeyWords.add(captionString);
        i++;

    }

    private void displayKeyWord(){
        if(i==chars.length){
            i=0;
        }
        captionString = chars[i];
        rainKeyWords.add(captionString);
        lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
        i++;
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        // clear the screen with a dark blue color. The
        // arguments to glClearColor are the red, green
        // blue and alpha component in the range [0,1]
        // of the color to be used to clear the screen.
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // tell the camera to update its matrices.
        camera.update();

        // tell the SpriteBatch to render in the
        // coordinate system specified by the camera.
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        // begin a new batch and draw the bucket and
        // all drops
        batch.begin();

        if(j==5){
            j=0;
        }

        batch.draw(background,0,0);
        batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);
        batch.draw(dropImage[j], raindrop.x, 400);

        /*for(Rectangle raindrop: raindrops) {
            batch.draw(dropImage[i], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
            //font.draw(batch, captionString, raindrop.x+45, raindrop.y+30);
        }*/

        batch.end();

        /*// process user input
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
            touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touchPos);
            bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) bucket.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) bucket.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        // make sure the bucket stays within the screen bounds
        if(bucket.x < 0) bucket.x = 0;
        if(bucket.x > 800 - 64) bucket.x = 800 - 64;

        // check if we need to create a new raindrop*/
        if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnRaindrop();



        // move the raindrops, remove any that are beneath the bottom edge of
        // the screen or that hit the bucket. In the later case we play back
        // a sound effect as well.
        Iterator<CustomRectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
            raindrop.y -= 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if(raindrop.y + 64 < 0) iter.remove();
            if(raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
                dropSound.play();
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // dispose of all the native resources
        dropImage[j].dispose();
        bucketImage.dispose();
        dropSound.dispose();
        rainMusic.dispose();
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: one string shared over multiple place so your all text changed same time.

Answer (score 0):

Now, the code where it looks like you draw the letters are commented out, but I assume this is what you intend to use.

```
for(Rectangle raindrop: raindrops) {
        batch.draw(dropImage[i], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
        font.draw(batch, captionString, raindrop.x+45, raindrop.y+30);
}
```

What this means: for each object in the raindrops array, you draw the captionString. So if you have 20 objects in raindrops and captionString = "a", then you will draw the letter "a" 20 times.

You are using a single string to represent 20 strings. A String can only hold a single value. So, the last value you give captionString, is the only value you can display using it. You don't change the value in the loop.

Every raindrop object needs to have its own string value. And this value is the one you will need to draw, not captionString.

[edit]

Looks like you already have this in place. Just use the right string.

Try:

```
for(Rectangle raindrop: raindrops) {
        batch.draw(dropImage[i], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
        font.draw(batch, raindrop.keyWord, raindrop.x+45, raindrop.y+30);
}
```